# Strange thing happening in command prompt

Tags: root, command-line, prompt

I'm using Ubuntu in command line mode, no GUI. I'm new to UNIX, so I'm a bit confused by something that just happened. I accidentally typed "suspend" instead of "pm-suspend", and my root~#: prompt disappeared. Now, whatever I try to enter just gives me a line break, and pressing keys like esc, gives me ^[, the arrow keys are all something along the lines of ^[^[[D. What can I do to return to the normal shell prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`suspend` is a bash built-in command, what it does as per the man page is:

```
 suspend [-f]
          Suspend  the execution of this shell until it receives a SIGCONT
          signal.  A login shell cannot be suspended; the -f option can be
          used to override this and force the suspension.  The return sta‐
          tus is 0 unless the shell is a login shell and -f  is  not  sup‐
          plied, or if job control is not enabled.
```

Thus your shell is suspended and will be until you send it a `SIGCONT` signal. The behavior you see is because the shell is not interpreting those characters.

To fix this:

1. Go to another virtual console (press alt-F3 or something) and log in.
2. use pkill to send the CONT signal to all processes named `bash`. This won't affect other running shells but should "unstick" the stuck one.

   `pkill -CONT bash`

Comment: Alt-f3 does nothing. Any other way to log into a different virtual console?

Comment: (1) Try the other `Alt` key on your keyboard, and make sure you hthat would keep an `Alt` key from behaving like `Alt`. (2) You can try `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F3`. (3) You can try a function key besides `F3`, from `F1` to `F6` (one of them is the shell you're in...if it's `F3`, that would explain your problem). (4) This shouldn't be happening if you didn't give the `-f` flag, unless you started this shell from something that is not a shell. Try `Ctrl`+`C` and  (if that doesn't help) `Ctrl`+`D`.

Comment: None of that works

Comment: If you know your system's IP address and installed openssh-server, you can ssh into it and do this. Otherwise, if you're unable to switch to another console, it may be running in single-user mode, in this case, you can simply reboot the system to regain control.

Comment: @Verandaguy it's <ctrl>+<alt>+<F3>.